# Make a dataframe which contains tag-information to EACH sentence in R

Tags: r

I have serveral sentences with opinion-tags, and I want a dataframe to show the information

```
test = c("I very/AD very/AD like/POS the voice/FE","I really really/AD hate/NEG you/FE","I love/POS and adore/POS him although he is rude/NEG")

> test
[1] "I very/AD very/AD like/POS the voice/FE"             
[2] "I really really/AD hate/NEG you/FE"                  
[3] "I love/POS and adore/POS him although he is rude/NEG"


> test = strsplit(test, ' ')
[[1]]
[1] "I" "very/AD" "very/AD" "like/POS" "the" "voice/FE"

[[2]]
[1] "I" "really" "really/AD" "hate/NEG" "you/FE"   

[[3]]
[1] "I" "love/POS" "and" "adore/POS" "him" "although" "he" "is" "rude/NEG"
```

With the data above, **I want to** make a dataframe contain tags' information to EACH sentence like this.

```
  POS NEG AD FE
1   1   0  2 voice
2   0   1  1 you
3   2   1  0
```

Now, **all I can do** is just to make a dataframe with total sum-up information like this.

```
  POS NEG AD    FE
1   3   2  3 voice
2   3   2  3   you
```

I can make it by using these codes below (I wrote them just in case you might use them to get a hint)

```
POS = grepl(pattern = "POS", unlist(test))
POS = length(POS[POS == T])
POS

NEG = grepl(pattern = "NEG", unlist(test))
NEG = length(NEG[NEG == T])
NEG

AD = grepl(pattern = "AD", unlist(test))
AD = length(AD[AD == T])
AD

FE = data.frame(word=unlist(test))
FE$match = grepl(pattern = "FE", unlist(test))
FE = FE[FE$match == T,]
FE =  gsub('\\/FE','', FE$word) 

data.frame(POS,NEG,AD,FE)
```

Again, what I aim is to make a dataframe which contains important tag-information to EACH sentence.(the answer codes may work regardless of the number of sentences because the test data can have more sentences)

```
  POS NEG AD FE
1   1   0  2 voice
2   0   1  1 you
3   2   1  0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
res <- t(sapply(strsplit(test, " "), function(x) {
        i1 <- grep("[/]", x)
        x1 <- x[i1]
        d1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(x1, "[/]"))[2:1]
        colnames(d1) <- c("key", "val")
        d1$key <- factor(d1$key, levels = c("POS", "NEG", "AD", "FE"))
        t1 <- t(table(d1))
        colSums(t1)}))
library(stringr)
res[,4] <- str_extract(test, "\\w+(?=/FE)")
```

Comment: What about dealing with lists in FE variable?

Comment: @Rcoding fixed that issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want a data.frame, you can use a `plyr::ldply` function:

```
ldply(test,
      function(t){

        FE <- strsplit(unlist(t), ' ')[[1]]
        FE <-  FE[grepl(pattern = "FE", FE)]
        FE <-  gsub('\\/FE','', FE) 

        data.frame(
          POS = sum(grepl(pattern = "POS", strsplit(t, ' '))),
          NEG = sum(grepl(pattern = "NEG", strsplit(t, ' '))),
          AD  = sum(grepl(pattern =  "AD", strsplit(t, ' '))),
          FE  = ifelse(length(FE) == 0, '', FE))
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_count` from `stringr` can be a way to go, i.e.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(c('POS', 'NEG', 'AD', 'FE'), function(i) str_count(test, i))
#     POS NEG AD FE
#[1,]   1   0  2  1
#[2,]   0   1  1  1
#[3,]   2   1  0  0
```

to get the list at `FE`, then,

```
m1[,'FE'] <- replace(m1[,'FE'], m1[,'FE'] == 1, 
             gsub('/.*', '', unlist(sapply(strsplit(test, ' '), function(i)
                                                       grep('/FE', i, value = TRUE)))))
m1
#     POS NEG AD  FE     
#[1,] "1" "0" "2" "voice"
#[2,] "0" "1" "1" "you"  
#[3,] "2" "1" "0" "0"
```